# Formula expression required for actionsupport error in customized picklist approach

Tags: javascript, picklist, actionsupport, getelementsbyclassname

I have a selectoption in apex page. The User selected value, I need to set to Category__c picklist field as value. Then I have a dependent picklist Segment__c that will work accordingly. I am trying as below. But it gives Compile Error as :  `Error: Formula expression is required for attribute action in <apex:actionSupport>`

**Apex Code**

```
  <apex:inputField value="{!accntTier.Category_Name_abv__c}" id="cat1"/>
                <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('{!$Component.cat1}').style.display = 'none';

       function picklistupd(ele)
       { var cat1= document.getElementById('{!$Component.cat1}').value;       
        cat1.value = ele.value;
         cat1.selected = "selected";
        alert(cat1.value);
        alert(ele.value);}
    </script>  
             <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.cat1}').style.display = 'none';</script>
              <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                 <apex:selectList styleClass="requiredInput" required="true" value="{!CategoryID}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!queueListSelectCategoryOption}" id="categoryPicklist"/>
                <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('{!$Component.categoryPicklist}').selected = 'selected';
         </script>
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="cat1,seg" oncomplete="picklistupd(this);" />
            </apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to call JavaScript function so you need `onComplete` as action attribute is used to call apex controller function.

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="cat1" oncomplete="picklistupd(this);"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help me know why alert here gives undefined? Anyway you answered me exactly what I needed and I marked your answer. Just an additional help if you please.

Comment: @javascript_learner you need to check what you are getting in ele